# When do we not gain any reputation from edits?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I think there are various rules about when a user gains and when he/she doesn't gain reputation for edits.
One of them is when he/she has already gained 1000 rep from suggested edits, another when he/she improves the edit during reviewing.

But I think there must be more rules because I have ceased to gain any reputation from edits, probably since I crossed 2000 rep.

So is there a rule that 2000+ reputed users may not gain rep from edits,  maybe because the edits are not reviewed?

BTW if there is such a rule, I think it is good. If it is a bug, make it a rule or fix it.

<sup>I am adding three tags because I don't know which one of them I'm really asking for ;P</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah you only get reputation for *suggested* edits that pass through the review system. And only up to a limit of 1k reputation. After you reach 2k, your edits are no longer suggested edits, they're just edits.

This is purposely so newer, less confident users can earn some reputation to get going.