# Can't thumb up my favorite answers?

Tags: discussion

I find lots of good answers on this forum but can't thumb them up because of missing reputation. Comments also are prohibited. Could someone just help me with that so I could reward my HEROES !
So how people start on this forum ?
Thanks !

PS: even creating new tags is not possible for me.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @ElderGeek Read that - so nothing could be done from the beginning other than posting a question and waiting to get reputation from it ? I don't remember doing that on SO ...

Comment: Also see this: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1209/how-do-i-quickly-gain-reputation

Comment: This is not a forum, it's a Q & A site. Follow the first link in my answer to begin getting up to speed. Cheers!

Comment: @ToleaBivol no, you probably did it in [wordpress.se], and got 200 reputation there. Then, you joined SO and since you had 200 reputation on another network site, you got the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/203101). You then dropped under 200 reputation on [wordpress.se], so when you joined [ubuntu.se], you didn't get the association, so you never reached the minimum reputation needed for voting. This is just a guess, but it seems like the likeliest explanation.

Comment: @terdon nice theory but I joined SO first, then wordpress. As I remember - I started in both by adding answers. Maybe something changed ...

Comment: You can always answer, and ask, questions. Voting takes [a tiny bit of rep](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up), yes. But this has been the case since day one. You probably just asked or answered, and were voted up, before you tried voting on the other sites.

Comment: one small thing though : "You must have at least 5 reputation on Ask Ubuntu to answer a question on meta."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [by design.](https://askubuntu.com/tour)

Consider [editing](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8881/when-do-we-not-gain-any-reputation-from-edits) and [asking good questions](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as writing [good answers.](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)

All of these activities lead to reputation increase over time. It's worked for me, I'm sure it can work for you.

Comment: I don't want to edit or ask questions. I asked this one because I was missing the ability so many thumbs up to really good answers. Even here I don't get reputation for it :D But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to get more reputation. There is no other way. Try interacting with more questions and answers in the topics you can help. Making questions is the fastest way to learn and get reputation.

Low reputation accounts are not considered because of spam.